# How to store/use external function pointers within a class vector

Tags: c++, vector, function-pointers

I'm using a `vector` in a class to store *MQTT topics* and *pointers to the external functions* that process the MQTT messages for each topic. I use a `typedef` to define the mqtt callback function pointers outside the class, and use that typedef in a struct that defines the `vector` objects.

However, I'm getting a compile error _'mqttCallback_t' has not been declared_ when I try to use the `typedef` to define the function pointer in the member function that will add objects to the vector.

```
void addSubscription(char* topic, mqttCallback_t* cback) {
```

I'm hoping someone can explain why the compiler generates this message, and what needs to be done to make the following code work.

```
// define pointer to an MQTT callback function that is external to the class
typedef void (*mqttCallback_t)(char*, byte*, unsigned int); 

class MqttClient{
    struct MqttSubscription {
        char topic[64];
        mqttCallback_t* callback;
    };
  private:
    byte brokerIP[4];
    uint16_t maxPacketLength;   
    bool sessionActive;
    std::vector<MqttSubscription> subList;
  public:
    void addSubscription(char* topic, mqttCallback_t* cback) {
        MqttSubscription sub;
        strncpy(sub.topic, topic, sizeof(sub.topic));
        sub.callback = cback;
        this->subList.push_back(sub);
    }
);
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/VrBNYy) using the exact code you showed.  Are `mqttCallback_t` and `MqttClient` defined in the same file?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to run a test ... My code is compiled exactly as shown above.

Comment: I am using the ARM GCC CPP Compiler to create firmware for an IOT device, so my code has empty setup() and loop() functions rather than a main(). That's the only real difference from your code.

Comment: Nitpicking: your `mqttCallback_t` is a function type, not a function pointer type.  And the parentheses around it do nothing.  And POSIX reserves `_t` names.

Comment: You're right ... I changed the typedef to *mqttCallback_t, but I see the same compile error. (Thanks for the POSIX tip. I'll fix that as soon as I get it working.)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a compiler issue:

The pre-processor was declaring the class forward. In other words, the compiler was trying to compile the class before the typedef.

Moving the typedef to a .h file solved the issue.

Thanks to those who added comments.